# sed: 1: "airports_need2_noheader ...": command a expects \ followed by text

Tags: bash, csv, sed, command

```
sed -i "iata:ID, name" airports_need2_noheader.csv
```

I got this problem when I was going to insert a header into a csv file, how to fix it?

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/unix-sed-tutorial-append-insert-replace-and-count-file-lines/#insert_lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insertion is a little tricky. Try:

```
sed '1i\
iata:ID, name
' airports_need2_noheader.csv
```